# Recurring error of Function host is not running

Tags: azure-functions

I am getting following error message every few days:

> Repository has more than 10 non-decryptable secrets backups (host).
> Two or more function apps are sharing the same secrets
> (functionName1.azurewebsites.net,functionName2.azurewebsites.net).

10 days ago, I had deleted the *.snapshot.{timestamp}.json files from Azure Function App using FTP client (ref: http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2021/11/fix-azure-functions-error-repository.html). But then I saw the master key of the 2nd azure function app got changed and the first app now shows error as: Function host is not running.

I am having similar configuration on few clients and dev environments, but occurring this error only for 1 client.

What could be causing this error every few days? Any reference would be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: You can have only up to 10 `snapshots` for the same `function app` or `logic app`. If you exceed this limit, you get the mentioned error. You need to delete those older secret backup files from the respective storage container. Refer [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/edit-app-settings-host-settings?tabs=azure-portal)

Comment: Thanks Anand! Are these snapshots created on some specific action like deployment of new updates to the function or on restart etc? Also the same is error isn't occurring for other clients. What configuration may I be missing?

Comment: Yes deployment of new versions, recreation and push from VS could cause these snapshots. Also, sharing of app service plan by many function apps could be also a cause.

Comment: Thanks! If sharing of app service plan by many function apps can cause this, I will have to recreate the app in new app service plan.

Answer (score 0):

You can have only up to 10 `snapshots` for a function app or logic app. If you exceed this limit, you get the mentioned error.
You need to delete those older secret backup files from the respective storage container. Refer this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/edit-app-settings-host-settings?tabs=azure-portal) , read the section for `host.json`.